# Apply command on all files in a folder

Tags: shell-script

I have a folder full of videos which all have 2 audio tracks and I want to remove the first one from each of them.

So I need to run:

```
ffmpeg -i [filename] -map 0:0 -map 0:2 -acodec copy -vcodec copy temp.mp4
mv temp.mp4 [filename]
```

on every file in that folder.

Comment: What have you tried so far? The thing you are looking for is called `for loop` in bash.

Answer (score 3):

```
find . -type f \
       -exec ffmpeg -i '{}' -map 0:0 -map 0:2 -acodec copy -vcodec copy temp.mp4 \; \
       -exec mv temp.mp4 '{}' \;`
```

Comment: The `mv` is not going to work as you have it.

Comment: Corrected. It should work now.

Answer (score 1):

I would use `find` with `-exec`:

```
find . -type f -name "*.mp4" -exec ffmpeg -i {} -map 0:0 -map 0:2 -acodec copy -vcodec copy {} \;
```

But a `ls -1 *.mp4 | ffmpeg` also works fine.

Answer (score 1):

```
for file in $(ls)
do
    #whatever you want to do with "${file}"
done
```

Comment: Careful with that -- `touch "a b"`

Comment: Oh... Quotation mark added (if that's what you mean).